# Quickest way to get Expression Engine v 2.5.5 working with PHP7

Tags: php, upgrade, php-7, expressionengine

A client’s host has recently updated their server to run PHP 7, which has broken their EE 2.5.5. site (“Call to undefined function mysql_connect()”).

I tried upgrading EE to version 2.11.9 but get errors:

Frontend: can’t find safecracker_lib

Control Panel: PATH_MOD not defined in mod_structure.php, fixing this leads down a rabbit hole starting with an error related to not being able to instantiate the pagination class somewhere.

I just need to get the site running until I build a new site, what is the quickest way I can get the site running with PHP 7?

Comment: The latest version is 5.4. Why are you trying to install 10 year old version? Just upgrade to the latest one.

Comment: I just need to get the site working for a couple of weeks, updating the plugins is way out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config folder there is a file named database.php
change the line:

```
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) has been deprecated since PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7 so you cannot use this function or any of the old `mysql` functions.

You need to upgrade your codebase, or downgrade your PHP version (**highly discouraged)**.

In regards to your missing pagination class, you may not have implemented core classes that were required when upgrading.

Try running on your command line:

```
php system/ee/eecms upgrade
```

You can also read the documentation on how to upgrade the codebase for Expression Engine [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/updating.html).

Comment: thank you, but ee2 doesn't have an 'ee' folder it's 'expressionengine' so I doubt that script is going to work, I've read the upgrade instructions, followed them and received the error mentioned.

Comment: I hope you aren't upgrading your old codebase to an old codebase; reading the documentation for "ee" tells me it's in version 5...

Comment: It may seem like a mammoth task for in the long run it's better to update the codebase to the lately version and keep on-top of all updates for security patches and bug fixes.

Comment: I am just trying to upgrade to 2.11.9 as upgrading the plugins is way beyond current scope